# Python read query from text file (sqlite3.OperationalError )

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to read queries from text file. But there are error

```
    sqlite3.OperationalError: near "DELETE": syntax error
```

My code is:

```
    import codecs
    import sqlite3

    conn = sqlite3.connect('D:\\db.sqlite')
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    def main():   
        with codecs.open('D:\\delete.txt','r',encoding='utf8') as myfile:
            cursor.executescript(myfile.read())
            conn.commit()
        conn.close()

    if __name__ == '__main__' : main()
```

My text file is:

```
    DELETE FROM table1 WHERE  id = 1;
    DELETE FROM table1 WHERE  id = 2;
```

What is wrong? Please help me

Comment: I have tested it on RH 6.4. It works for me. Can you place breakpoint or just print result of myfile.read(). It looks like it reads file incorrectly

Comment: @user1209304 print result myfile.read() is:  `DELETE FROM table1 WHERE  id = 1; DELETE FROM table1 WHERE  id = 2;`

Comment: My platform is Win 7 64bit, python 3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the first 3 characters of your file... you'll probably find a UTF8 byte order mark (BOM) there `(0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF)`.

To remove the BOM, open your file with 'utf-8-sig' encoding:

```
codecs.open('D:\\delete.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I change my file encoding uft-8 -> utf-8 without BOM